# Apache2: Redirect to higher page and cut everything after ? (questionmark)

Tags: redirect, get, apache2, cut

I need to redirect

```
www.example.com/members/?name=bla&test=dgdg
www.example.com/members/?anything=any&test=dgdg
```

permanently to

```
www.example.com/members/
```

within a VirtualHost configuration of Apache.
I tried

```
RedirectMatch ^members/\?(.*) www.example.com/members

RedirectMatch ^members/(.+) www.example.com/members
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/members/(.+) www.example.com/members [R=301]
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^/members/ /member/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$` checks whether QUERY_STRING is empty, `QSD` removes QUERY_STRING on redirect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. When I try it, Chrome and Firefox tell me "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS", as always when I try to test it...

Comment: @MichelvanM Let me check it. It should not do it without the QUERY_STRING